# Select rows from pandas that contain given string in list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select the rows from dataframe that have "apple" in their column, but the "PHRASE" column should not be considered as string but as a list with "|" separator. Phrase column can have None/NaN values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"PHRASE": ["apple and bannaa|bannana", None, "apple", "orange|bannana", "orange|apple|bannana"]})

print(df)

0  apple and bannaa|bannana
1                     apple
2            orange|bannana
3      orange|apple|bannana
```

I want to select rows that have apple in them, but the row should be considered as list with "|" as separator.

Desired output:

```
1                     apple
3      orange|apple|bannana
```

I tried to do this

```
result = df[df.PHRASE.str.split("|").str.contains("apple")]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, it works good, but I forgot to add one thing in my question (I have updated it not), PHRASE column can have None/Nan values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `str.contains` but with a regex pattern

```
df[df['PHRASE'].str.contains(r'\bapple(?:\||$)', na=False)]
```

---

```
                 PHRASE
1                 apple
3  orange|apple|bannana
```

Comment: Thanks, it works good, but I forgot to add one thing in my question (I have updated it not), PHRASE column can have None/Nan values

Comment: Please check the edit, I have added an optional `na=False` parameter to account for the null values

Comment: This is a good solution : I had a similar approach with regex but this is better!

Comment: Your solution is amazing!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.loc[[isinstance(splitted, list) and "apple" in splitted 
        for splitted in df.PHRASE.str.split("|")]]
```

(`isinstance(splitted, list)` is added to prevent NaN et al.)

After your splitting, let's run a list comprehension to produce True/False's depending on the list in a given row has "apple" in it. Rest is boolean indexing:

```py
In [129]: df
Out[129]:
                     PHRASE
0  apple and bannaa|bannana
1                     apple
2            orange|bannana
3      orange|apple|bannana
4                       NaN

In [130]: df.PHRASE.str.split("|")
Out[130]:
0    [apple and bannaa, bannana]
1                        [apple]
2              [orange, bannana]
3       [orange, apple, bannana]
4                            NaN
Name: PHRASE, dtype: object

In [131]: [isinstance(splitted, list) and "apple" in splitted
     ...:  for splitted in df.PHRASE.str.split("|")]
Out[131]: [False, True, False, True, False]

In [132]: df.loc[_]
Out[132]:
                 PHRASE
1                 apple
3  orange|apple|bannana
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `str.split` then `explode` the list to rows

```py
mask = (df['PHRASE'].str.split('|')
        .explode().eq('apple')
        .groupby(level=0).any())
```

```
print(mask)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: PHRASE, dtype: bool

print(df[mask])

                 PHRASE
2                 apple
4  orange|apple|bannana
```